# android fragment animation using compatibility package

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

How can I use animation for transitions between fragments ? I tried

```
FragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,
                                                 android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

changing the animation to different kind of animations, but it always seems to animate like fading-in while pushing fragment and fading out while popping fragment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know this question is very old, but I stumbled upon it while looking for an answer to this myself.

I'm currently using animations in my compatibility package, fragment based app, and it's actually quite simple.

Add this before actually adding / replacing the fragments:

```
FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,
                android.R.anim.slide_out_right, android.R.anim.slide_in_left,
                android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

Your new fragment will slide in from the left on push, and slide out to the right on pop.

Of course this also works for other default animations, or custom animations.

Comment: I'll add here that it's important you call setCustomAnimations() BEFORE you call add() or replace(), otherwise it is ignored. That undocumented thing cost me some time. Also you can specify 0 for arguments where you don't need animations.
See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972540/