# Fragment animation : difference between setCustomAnimations and setTransitionStyle

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I'd like to animate the transition between two fragments which is performed thanks to `FragmentTransaction.replace()`. I'd like to specify my custom animation in a XML file.

What is the difference between calling `FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations()` and `FragmentTransaction.setTransitionStyle()` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[`setCustomAnimations(int, int, int, int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) allows you to specify your animation resources directly. If you use [`setTransitionStyle(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setTransitionStyle%28int%29), on the other hand, you'll have to specify them by using a [FragmentAnimation style](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#FragmentAnimation) and [`setTransition(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setTransition%28int%29).

It is worth mentioning that **the compatibility library ignores** [`setTransitionStyle(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setTransitionStyle%28int%29), so if you are using it you have to use [`setCustomAnimations(int, int, int, int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#setCustomAnimations%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) for sure.

For more info on this, check out this [excellent post about Fragment states and Fragment animations](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2012/06/fragment-transactions-reference.html)

Comment: MAAAAAAn thanl you for the link!

Comment: I'll add here that it's important you call `setCustomAnimations()` **BEFORE** you call `add()` or `replace()`, otherwise it is ignored. That undocumented thing cost me some time. Also you can specify 0 for arguments where you don't need animations.

Comment: perfect , be carefull to use ft.setCustomAnimations before  ft.replace 

it solved my problem

Comment: It looks like the support library has improved transistion support since this answer.  21 (October 2014) and 24.2.0 (August 2016) specifically.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html